proof of $\frac{(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)..}{(1+q)(1+q^2)(1+q^3)..} = 1 - 2 q + 2 q^4 - 2 q^9 +~..$
I came across the following fascinating identity involving infinite products and series:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)..}{(1+q)(1+q^2)(1+q^3)..} &=&(1-2q+2q^2-2q^3+~..)(1-2q^2+2q^4-2q^6+~..)(1-2q^3+2q^6-2q^9+~..)\\
&=&1 - 2 q + 2 q^4 - 2 q^9 +~..
\end{eqnarray}
Can someone provide a proof of this equivalence? I'm interested in understanding the connection.
I attempted the following:

Expanding the product term by term.

1.1 Expand $(1-2q+2q^2-2q^3+~..)(1-2q^2+2q^4-2q^6+~..)$
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
&1 & -2 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -2 & 2 \\
&  &    &-2 &  4 & -4 & 4 & -4 & 4 & -4 & 4 & -4 & 4 & -4 \\
&  &    &   &    & 2 & -4 &  4 & -4 & 4 & -4 & 4 & -4 & 4 \\
&  &    &   &    &   &    & -2 & 4 & -4 & 4 & -4 & 4 & -4 \\
&  &    &   &    &   &    &    &   &  &   &  &  & ~..\\
=& 1 & -2   & 0  & 2 &  0 & -2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -2  & 0 & 2 & 0\\
\end{array}
$(1-2q+2q^2-~..)(1-2q^2+2q^4-~..) = 1 - 2 q + 2 q^3 - 2 q^5 + ~..$
1.2 Expand $(1-2q+2q^3-2q^5+~..)(1-2q^3+2q^6-2q^9+~..)$
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
&1 & -2 & 0  & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
&  &    &   & -2 & 4 & 0  & -4 & 0 & 4 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 4 \\
&  &    &   &    &   &    &  2 &-4 & 0 & 4 & 0 & -4 & 0 \\
&  &    &   &    &   &    &    &   &   & -2 & 4 & 0 & -4 \\
&  &    &   &    &   &    &    &   &   &   &  &  & ~..\\
=& 1 & -2   & 0  & 0 &  4 & -2 & -2 & -2 & 4 & 0  & 0 & -2 & 2\\
\end{array}
Pattern seems to break here.

Use functional equation

let
$$
P(q) = \frac{(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)~..}{(1+q)(1+q^2)(1+q^3)~..}
$$
then
$$
P(-q) = \frac{(1+q)(1-q^2)(1+q^3)~..}{(1-q)(1+q^2)(1-q^3)~..}
$$
therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
P(q) P(-q) &=& \frac{(1-q^2)^2(1-q^4)^2~..}{(1+q^2)^2(1+q^4)^2~..}\\
&=& P(q^2)^2
\end{eqnarray}
Now suppose
\begin{eqnarray}
P(q) &=& 1 + A q + B q^2 + C q^3 +~..\\
P(-q) &=& 1 - A q + B q^2 - C q^3 +~..\\
P(q^2) &=& 1 + A q^2 + B q^4 + C q^6 +~..\\
\end{eqnarray}
If I made no mistake, coefficient comparison yields
\begin{eqnarray}
2A &=& -A^2 + 2B \\
A^2 + 2B &=& B^2 - 2 A C + 2D\\
2AB +2C &=& -C^2 + 2BD - 2AE + 2F
\end{eqnarray}
But I'm stack here. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Hayashi, what did you try?

This is a really interesting identity, but as @Angelo has mentioned, "no idea" questions tend to get ignored here, so if you can show some ideas that you have tried that would be great.

@Angelo,@RedFive Thanks for suggestion. I added an explanation of my attempt.

What's the radius of convergence of that polynomial? Because if you evaluate the infinite quotient at $q=1$, it is $0$ but the polynomial yields something different but $0$...

The theta-4 function can be expressed as an infinite product:
$$\theta_{4}\left(z,q\right)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-q^{2n}\right)%
\left(1-2q^{2n-1}\cos\left(2z\right)+q^{4n-2}\right)$$
With $z=0$
$$\theta_{4}\left(0,q\right)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-q^{2n}\right)%
\left(1-2q^{2n-1}+q^{4n-2}\right) = \prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-q^{2n}\right)%
\left(1-q^{2n-1}\right)^2$$
Now note the following identity for infinite products:
$$ \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+q^n) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-q^{2n})}{(1-q^n)}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-q^{2n-1})}$$
you get
$$\theta_{4}\left(0,q\right)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-q^{2n}\right)%
\left(1-q^{2n-1}\right)^2 = \prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-q^n)}{(1+q^{n})} \tag{1}$$
Let's prove that this is equal to the series. Intuitively you may suspect that
$$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-2q^{2m-1}\cos(2z)+q^{4m-2}) = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-q^{2m})(1-2q^{2m-1}\cos(2z)+q^{4m-2})}{(1-q^{2n})} = \frac{1-2q\cos(2z)+2q^{4}\cos(4z)-2q^{9}\cos(6z)+\cdots}{\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-q^{2m})}$$
But let's prove it formally. Consider the following infinite product:
$$F(t,q) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+q^{2n-1}t)(1+q^{2n-1}t^{-1}) \quad t\neq 0 $$
This product has the following properties
$$ F(t^{-t},q) = F(t,q) \tag{*}$$
$$ qtF(q^2t,q) = F(t,q) \tag{**}$$
Property (*) is trivial. For property (**):
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(q^2t,q) &=& (1+q^3t)(1+q^5t)\cdots(1+q^{-1}t^{-1})(1+qt^{-1})(1+q^3t^{-1})\\
&=&\frac{1+q^{-1}t^{-1}}{1+qt} (1+qt)(1+q^3t)\cdots(1+qt^{-1})(1+q^3t^{-1})\cdots\\
&=&\frac{1}{qt}F(t,q)
\end{eqnarray*}
It can be proven that the product $F(t,q)$ converges uniformly with respect to $t,q$ and therefore $F(t,q)$ is analytic for $|q|<1, t\neq 0$ and consequently is expansible in a Laurent series:
$$F(t,q) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_nt^n$$
Property (*) implies $a_{n} = a_{-n}$
Property (**) requieres
$$qt\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_nq^{2n}t^{n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{n}t^n$$
Equating coefficients implies:
$$ a_{n} = q^{2n-1}a_{n-1}$$
Iterating:
$$ a_n = q^{2n-1}q^{2n-3}\cdots q^3qa_0 = q^{n^2}a_{0}$$
Hence
$$ F(t,q) = a_0\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2}t^{n}$$
If we put $t=-e^{2iz}$ we get
$$ F(-e^{2iz},q) = a_{0}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^nq^{n^2}e^{2nzi} = a_0\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^2q^{n^2}\cos(2nz)\right)$$
If we put $z=0$
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{2n-1})^2  = a_0\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^2q^{n^2}\right)$$
From (1) we can conclude that $a_{0}$ should be
$$ a_0 = \frac{1}{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{2n})}$$
to attain the equation:
$$\boxed{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-q^n)}{(1+q^{n})} = 1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^2q^{n^2}}$$
A good reference is Lawden. Elliptic Functions and Applications
